# Como hacer para que el placeholder se alinee a la izquierda

Tags: html5, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que se alinie a la izquierda porque esta muy a la derecha

```
<div class="login.page">
  <div class="widget-shadow">
    <div class="login-body">
      <form action="thanks.html" onsubmit="validarformulario()">
        <span id="emailOK"></span>
        <div id="campo1"><input 
             type="text" class="textbox" size="30"  placeholder="Name" required>    </div>
        <div id="campo2"><input 
             type="text" id="email" name="email" class="textbox" 
             data-validation="email" size="30"  placeholder="Email " required></div>
        <div id="campo3"><input 
             type="text"  class="textbox" size="30" placeholder="Company" required>  </div>
        <input type="submit"  id="user" size="30"  value="GET EARLY ACCESS">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Amarisu. Puedes añadir el html y lo que has intentado? Usaas alguna libreria? Mira [ask] para aprender a hacer preguntas de mayor calidad. Un saludo

Comment: Revisa el padding y la alineación que tiene el input

Comment: Utilizas algun framework/

Comment: no no utilizo framework

Comment: Para lograr eso elimina o disminuye el `padding-left`, como le estas dando un pading de 80px no puede alinearse mas a la izquierda

Answer (score 3):

```css
.textbox {
    border: 1px solid #DBE1EB;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "hurmegeometricsans3_regularRg";
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: #E4E4E4;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Bootstrap Switch Demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">



</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="widget-shadow">
    <div class="login-body">
        <form action="thanks.html" onsubmit="validarformulario()">
          <span id="emailOK"></span>
          <div id="campo1">
            <input type="text" class="textbox" size="30" placeholder="Name" required> 
          </div>
          <div id="campo2">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="textbox" data-validation="email" size="30" placeholder="Email" required>
          </div>
          <div id="campo3">
            <input type="text" class="textbox" size="30" placeholder="Company" required>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" id="user" size="30" value="GET EARLY ACCESS">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

El placeholder lo tiene un input, este input tiene una clase llamada `textbox` a la cual le estas colocando un `padding-left: 80px;` lo cual te genera un espacio a la izquierda, si quieres tenerlo un poco mas a la izquierda tienes que bajarle al `padding-left` mira el ejemplo a continuación.

Answer (score 3):

En la clase `.textbox` tienes `padding-left: 80px;`, puedes cambiar la propiedad a un `padding-left: 40px;`, por ejemplo, para reducirlo.

```css
.textbox {
  border: 1px solid #DBE1EB;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "hurmegometrcsans3_regularRg";
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: #E4E4E4;
  color: #2E3133;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-shadow">
  <div class="login-body">
    <form action="thanks.html">
      <span id="emailOK"></span>
      <div id="campo1"><input 
         type="text" class="textbox" size="30" placeholder="Name" required></div>
      <div id="campo2"><input 
         type="text" id="email" name="email" class="textbox" 
         data-validation="email" size="30" placeholder="Email " required></div>
      <div id="campo3"><input 
         type="text" class="textbox" size="30" placeholder="Company" required></div>
      <input type="submit" id="user" size="30" value="GET EARLY ACCESS">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esto cambiara el estilo para todas los elementos que tenga esta clase, si quieres que solo afecte estos textbox solo agrega una nueva clase mas detallada para atinarle a los elemento de interes.

Por ejemplo a la clase `login-body` del `div` padre del `form`:

```
 .login-body .textbox {
    padding-left: 40px;
 }
```

y asi los elementos (textbox, etc.) que sean hijos del que tenga la clase `login-body` tendrán este estilo.

```css
.textbox {
  border: 1px solid #DBE1EB;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "hurmegometrcsans3_regularRg";
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: #E4E4E4;
  color: #2E3133;
}

.login-body .textbox {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-shadow">
  <div class="login-body">
    <form action="thanks.html">
      <span id="emailOK"></span>
      <div id="campo1"><input 
        type="text" class="textbox" size="30" placeholder="Name" required></div>
      <div id="campo2"><input 
        type="text" id="email" name="email" class="textbox" 
        data-validation="email" size="30" placeholder="Email " required></div>
      <div id="campo3"><input 
        type="text" class="textbox" size="30" placeholder="Company" required></div>
      <input type="submit" id="user" size="30" value="GET EARLY ACCESS">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```